# +100 bonus appears to have posted twice to my Area 51 account

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51

I reached 200 rep on Web Applications today, so I see that I got a +100 bonus on all of the other sites (which I understand is normal).  On Area 51, it appears to have happened twice, though.  Is that a bug?  I'm showing 251 rep on Area 51 (51 for signing up and confirming e-mail + 100 bonus + another 100 bonus?)  Not that I'm complaining, but it seems like something could be wrong there...

The double bonus didn't happen on any of the other sites.  My rep page on Area 51 says "There aren't yet any reputation changes to show."

Comment: hmm.. looks like it. meh, rep on Area51 is useless anyway...

Comment: What happens if you go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation and hit `recalc`?

Comment: total votes: 3
-- bonuses   (250)
-- 2011-09-22 rep 0     = 251       

** total rep 251 :)

days represented 2
rep cap was reached on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We just fixed an Area 51 bug that made it possible to receive the +100 bonus twice if you crossed 200 rep on another site, then manually associated your accounts on Area 51.

I cleaned up the bad data and recalculated reputation for the 64 affected users, so your A51 reputation is back down to 151. Thanks for the heads up.